# WPF item.Content.ToString() / ListBox Code

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to c# and WPF and there's a problem with `ListBoxItem.Content` property:

```
ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();
itm.Content = "klant aantalConsumpties";
listBoxOverzicht.Items.Add(itm);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```
foreach (var item in listBoxOverzicht.Items)
{ 
     if (item.ToString().Contains(klant))                       
     { 
          MessageBoxResult result= MessageBox.Show("Er is reeds een klant met als naam " + item.Content.ToString() + ".\n" +
           "Klik op JA als je de consumpties "+
           "wilt toevoegen aan deze klant.\n" + 
           "Klik op NEE als je het om nieuwe klant gaat.\n"+
           "Klik Annuleren om input te wijzigen.","Opdracht 2", 
            MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

          switch (result)
          { 
               case etc....
```

I can't use `item.Content.ToString()` since I get the message:

> 'object'does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension
>   method accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are
>   u missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `Content`. `ToString()` is enough:

```
item.ToString()
```

If you want just specific property try this:

```
MessageBox.Show((item as Model).Name.ToString());
```

And finally in your case because you want the `Content` property of `ListBoxItem` you should try this:

```
MessageBox.Show((item as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString());
```

Comment: FAN-TAS-TIC. Thx very much! Works great now!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using simply item.ToString() instead assuming its a simple text listbox item.

If you are displaying more complex objects then you could cast to the object and display the appropriate property.